# Bootstrap 4 - centering the brand in navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center the brand in the navigation bar below. I tried changing the style so that the text is centered but nothing I tried worked. I attached a picture of what it looks like now. I just need the text to be centered instead of being formatted to the left.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLqDk.jpg)

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top flex-md-nowrap navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark shadow" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; background-color:var(--theme-gray)">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding: 0;">
        <img src="img/Cama-i Ellam Yui Logo - Header, Large.jpg"  alt="logo" style="height:65px;">
      </a>
        <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <span class="navbar-brand">Qaneryararvik: The Yup'ik Word Place</span>
    </div>
    </div>
<!-- Links -->
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Words</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Acknowledgements</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please follow the guidance in the duplicate: https://www.codeply.com/go/kEIMWrqqOe

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS:

```
.navbar-header{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or

You can use w-100 & text-center classes of Bootstrap.

```
<div class="navbar-header w-100 text-center">
    <span class="navbar-brand">Qaneryararvik: The Yup'ik Word Place</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Media query`

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-brand
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mx-auto` in *navbar-header* class to to center align.

```
<div class="navbar-header mx-auto">
    <span class="navbar-brand">Qaneryararvik: The Yup'ik Word Place</span>
</div>
```